# Get sum of multiplication of two column values from unrelated tables in cart

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

In my laravel ecommerce project 
I have 2 tables in the database :

```
 cart [c_id(pk), laundry, l1, dryclean, dc1, dc2, dc3, shop_id]
 price [p_id, p_l1, p_dc1, p_dc2, p_dc3, shop_id]
```

In controller I get prices of logged in shop i.e. single row

```
$price = DB::table('price')->where('price.shop_id', '=', auth()->id())->get();
```

also to get a row from cart table I am taking the most recent entry

```
$cart = DB::table('cart')->latest()->first();
```

Laundry and dryclean columns from cart table can have two values YES and NO. If laundry is yes then user also enters l1(which is quantity) else null.

similarly, for dryclean column can have two values YES and NO. If YES then user also enters dc1, dc2, dc3(quantities of items).

Now I want to get the Total amount on checkout page from controller including conditions where values of laundry and dryclean are checked.

So far I was calculating total in the view file.

```
@if ( $cart->dryclean == "no")
    @php $c1=0;$c2=0;$c3=0; @endphp
@else
      @if (is_null($cart->dc1))
      @php  $c1=0; @endphp
      @else
            @php
            $a1= $cart->dc1;
            $b1 =$price->p_dc1;
            $c1= $a1*$b1;
            @endphp
      @endif
      @if (is_null($cart->dc2))
      @php  $c2=0; @endphp
      @else
            @php
            $a2= $cart->dc2;
            $b2 =$price->p_dc2;
            $c2= $a2*$b2;
            @endphp
      @endif
      @if (is_null($cart->dc3))
      @php  $c3=0; @endphp
      @else
            @php
            $a3= $cart->dc3;
            $b3 =$price->p_dc3;
            $c3= $a3*$b3;
            @endphp
      @endif

      {{ $c1 + $c2 + $c3}}   <!-- This is total amount -->
      @endif
```

Please help me writing controller queries to calculate total amount in controller itself and display in the view.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you share some code from your view file of how you are calculating this?

Comment: I have posted some of code from view file.

Comment: did my answer give you what you needed? If so, can you mark it as correct?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the blade syntax of everything you did.

```
if ( $cart->dryclean == "no" ) {

    $c1 = 0;
    $c2 = 0;
    $c3 = 0;

} else {

    if ( is_null($cart->dc1) ) {

        $c1 = 0; 

    } else {

        $a1 = $cart->dc1;
        $b1 = $price->p_dc1;
        $c1 = $a1 * $b1;

    } 

    if ( is_null($cart->dc2) ) {

        $c2 = 0;

    } else {

        $a2 = $cart->dc2;
        $b2 = $price->p_dc2; 
        $c2 = $a2 * $b2;

    } 

    if ( is_null($cart->dc3) ) {

        $c3 = 0;

    } else {

        $a3 = $cart->dc3;
        $b3 = $price->p_dc3;
        $c3 = $a3 * $b3;

    }

    // total used to be calculated here

}

$total = $c1 + $c2 + $c3;


return view('your.view.here')->with('total', $total);
```

Some tips, based on what I see:

- Use a Boolean value in the $cart->dryclean field. This is easier to store and use than "yes" and "no".
- You were calculating the total in blade before you got to the end of your first"if" statement. If the dryclean value was no (or false), no total would have been given.
- For your own readability, I recommend using the full name, such as `$cost1`. I actually can't even tell if that is your intention because it just says 'c1'..
- You can bypass many of the calculations by using the null coalesce operator to give a default value if the first one is null.

If you take my tips, you could have your controller be like the example below.

```
if ( $cart->dryclean ) {

    $cost1 = ($cart->dc1 ?? 0) * $price->p_dc1;

    $cost2 = ($cart->dc2 ?? 0) * $price->p_dc2;

    $cost3 = ($cart->dc3 ?? 0) * $price->p_dc3;

} else {

    $cost1 = 0;
    $cost2 = 0;
    $cost3 = 0;

}

$total = $cost1 + $cost2 + $cost3;

return view('your.view.here')->with('total', $total);
```

If you wanted to take it a step further, you could do this (using the ternary operator):

```
// set class properties
$this->cart = $cart;
$this->price = $price;

$total = ( $cart->dryclean )
         ? $this->costOf('1') + $this->costOf('2') + $this->costOf('3')
         : 0;

return view('your.view.here')->with('total', $total);
```

Of course, this is using another private function outside of the original controller function:

```
private funtion costOf($number)
{
return ( $this->cart->{'dc'.$number} ?? 0 ) * $this->price->{'p_dc'.$number};
}
```

This `costOf` function is using the string version of the number to grab the associated fields on each model type.